# Words derived from "Kinder"?

Tags: word-choice

My understanding is that *kinderlos* means childLESS.

In the opposite vein, I once described a woman as "kinder fähig." That literally means "child capable," and would refer to someone's ability to bear children. Is that a real German word, or is it another one of my "inventions"?

And "Kinderkriegen" means childbearing, right? Or is it a reference to the "begetting" of children.

So if I wanted to say that a certain woman was "capable of bearing children, would I say that she's "kinder fähig," or "kinder kriegen fähig," or use another term altogether?

Comment: I wonder, why no one mentioned “Kinderschokolade” – chocolate made from, no, _for_ children. ;-) (To be sure: It’s a trade mark.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answering the questions, as they come:

*kinderlos* is *childless*.

*kinderfähig* (not *kinder fähig)* is a word that someone might invent in German and that would be understood as intended (given an appropriate context). So it is not surprising, that [somebody on the Internet](http://www.google.de/search?q=kinderf%C3%A4hig#q=kinderf%C3%A4hig&tbs=li:1) has already done so – mostly in the context of something (e.g., furniture, a computer, a school) being suited for children. However in this context, I would prefer *kindergeeignet.*

*Kinderkriegen* may mean *childbearing,* but can also be used to refer to starting a family in general (which, to illustrate the difference, may also include adopting children).

The German term for the capability of a woman to bear children is *gebärfähig,* which literally means *capable of giving birth.*

Comment: @Takkat: Can I still read those comments somewhere, in some kind of history for the answer? I would like to see what was commented here.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Unfortunately people could not get bothered with a sum-up of their comments to add an answer. So no, you can't read them any more.

Answer (score 2):

Eine Frau, die Kinder kriegen kann, ist **fruchtbar**.

.

Comment: I would say that *fruchtbar* has a narrower point of view. A woman, that is pregrant right now or at a certain point of her period, is certainly capable of bearing a child, but not *fruchtbar.*

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Du würdest aber nicht behaupten sie sei unfruchtbar, oder?

Comment: Nein, würde ich nicht. Aber *un-* kann halt nicht immer durch *nicht* ersetzt werden (mir fällt gerade kein besseres Beispiel ein als *heilig* vs. *unheilig).*

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Zumindest der Duden sieht das etwas anders als Du: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/fruchtbar „die fruchtbaren Tage der Frau (Tage, an denen eine Empfängnis möglich ist)“. Ich halte den obigen Satz in dieser allgemeinen, zeitlich unbestimmten Forma aber auch für unpassend. „Zeugungsfähig“ wäre mMn das richtige, allerdings eher nach technicus terminus klingende Wort.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Mannomann, das sollte „Form“ und „terminus technicus“ heißen …

Comment: @Speravir: Ich kan Dir nicht ganz folgen. Dein Zitat steht doch in vollem Einklang mit meiner Aussage. Die dortige Definition nicht unbedingt, allerdings ist diese anscheinen für alle Lebewesen gefasst (ich denke kaum, dass bei Anwendung des Begriffes *fruchtbar* auf Menschen die Anzahl der Nachkommen im Blick hat). *zeugungsfähig* hat das Problem, dass *zeugen* vorwiegend für den männlichen Beitrag zum Vorgang verwendet wird.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Genau die von mir zitierte Passage widerspricht IMHO Deinem „A woman, … but not _fruchtbar_.” Nur darum ging es mir, ich bin schließlich grundsätzlich Deiner Meinung. Zu „zeugungsfähig“: Ja, das wird von vielen eher für Männer gebraucht, aber ich schrieb nicht umsonst (leicht falsch) „technicus terminus“, siehe auch [Zeugungsfähigkeit](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeugungsf%C3%A4higkeit) (dt. Wikipedia).

Comment: @Speravir: Das kann ich beim besten Willen nicht nachvollziehen. Ich formuliere den relevanten Teil meiner Aussage nochmal um: Eine Frau, die sich in einem gewissen Abschnitt ihres Zyklus befindet (nämlich den Tagen, an denen keine Empfängnis möglich ist), kann zwar gebärfähig sein, aber nicht fruchtbar.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Eine Frau, die akut nicht fruchtbar ist kann gleichwohl prinzipiell fruchtbar sein. Der Kontext macht nicht das Wort unmöglich. Man kann auch sagen "Jetzt spielt Frank Saxophon" weil er beim Konzert von 20-23:00 Uhr teilnimmt, und es eben 21:15 Uhr ist. Genaugenommen ist jetzt aber Pause, und er spielt gerade nicht, oder er hat im Stück 4 Takte Pause.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Shice, Du hast recht. Ich schieb's mal auf mein schlechtes Englisch.

Answer (score 1):

"she is capable of bearing children"

Sie ist fähig Kinder zu kriegen.

"kinderfähig" is not a word that any german would use. the short version is "fruchtbar"

Comment: If you use "fruchtbar" in this context in a discussion, you will get some very funny looks.

Comment: Compare your last sentence with the answer of “user unknown” … and the comments.

Comment: @patrix well, ifa woman goes to a doc to check if she is capable of becoming pregnant, he will certainly tell her that she is "fruchtbar"

Comment: He would talk about being "zeugungsfähig" or "in der Lage, Kinder zu kriegen" rather than "fruchbar".

Comment: wrong. men are "zeugungsfähig", women are "empfängnisfähig". genderneutral: "fruchtbar" ("fortpflanzungsfähig", but this is a rather biological term)